# AMI based on Ubuntu 18.04 AWS image does not have network interface

Tags: networking, 18.04, aws

I have an issue while creating an AMI based on the standard AWS Ubuntu 18.04 server image. This issue did not occur with Ubuntu 16.04.

When I boot a standard AWS Ubuntu 18.04 image and create a new AMI without touching anything on the image, I have no issue when using this new AMI to boot another instance.

However, if I simply run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

then create a new AMI and use it to boot a new instance, bang, no network interface, whatever the type of instance I try to launch. Usually an 'ens3' or 'eth0' network interface should appear.

I narrowed down the problem to be perhaps related to the new netplan network handler which is may be disturbed by the sudden installation of ubuntu-desktop and may be bad interaction with NetworkManager.

Any idea on the possible cause of this behavior?

**UPDATE**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-58:~$ ls -al /etc/netplan/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 19 04:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 88 root root 4096 Jun 19 04:10 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  473 Jun 19 04:10 50-cloud-init.yaml
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-58:~$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 02:7a:e7:bc:e8:c8
            set-name: ens3
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-58:~$ ifconfig
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.31.13.58  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.31.15.255
        inet6 fe80::7a:e7ff:febc:e8c8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:7a:e7:bc:e8:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 692  bytes 665816 (665.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 366  bytes 41639 (41.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 184  bytes 14306 (14.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 184  bytes 14306 (14.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `ls /etc/netplan` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and finally: `ifconfig`

Comment: See my updated post above. The output is of course AWS instance type dependent as 'ens3' could very well be 'eth0'. This file is created by cloud-init at boot time once it has extracted meta-data from AWS. Of course I cannot tell you what it looks like on the other instance based on the newly created AMI as it is lacking a network interface.

Comment: "I cannot tell you what it looks like on the other instance based on the newly created AMI" So the results posted above are *not* from the instance from which you are having trouble?

Comment: No, they are not. cloud-init is supposed to create this yaml file but for some reason a package and/or a set-up from ubuntu-update brings havoc to the set-up that otherwise works totally fine.

Comment: Installing ubuntu-desktop probably installs Network Manager. The netplan configurations are completely different for server vs. Network Manager. I suspect that is the underlying issue. Without diagnostics, it's difficult to fix. Is Network Manager running? `ps aux | grep etwork` Do you want networking in the faulty instance handled by netplan's yaml or by clicking the Network Manager icon to connect?

Comment: That was one of my first ideas. I disabled and masked (because it is wanted by multi-user.target) NetworkManager and purged the packet. No luck, it does not work too. You name it, it is pretty difficult to understand what is happening without having access to the instance.

Comment: If you don't have physical access and rely on ssh and ftp, I'm not sure what a desktop environment does to help.

Comment: It does. Not really the matter here though. The issue is that something is wrong with 18.04 release and needs to be corrected. Any idea where this should be reported?

Comment: I'm not sure that anything is wrong with the release since it works correctly until ubuntu-desktop is added. In any case, you can report bugs here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same problem.  It turns the `ifupdown` pkg is up to blame.  Simply removing it (`apt purge ifupdown`) should solve the problem.